# Performance one-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to define a one-to-many relationship with SqlAlchemy where I have Parent has many Child

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    id = Column(String, primary_key = True)
    children = relationship("Child")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True) 
    feed_type_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("parent.id"))
```

From business rules, Parent has no much Child (between 10 and 30) and most of the time I will need access to all of them so I think that it's good idea that relationship() retrieve all children in memory in order to increase performance (**First question:** am I right?) but Few times I need to get a particular child but I won't do something like:

```
def search_bar_attr(some_value)
    for bar in foo.bars:
        if(bar.attr == some_value)
            return bar
```

lazy="dynamic" returns a list that allows queries but I think it's slow against "eagerly" loaded because dynamic relationship always queries the database.

**Second question**: Is there some configuration that covers all my needs?

Comment: this would be difficult to answer generally. However, you can [specify loading strategy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) at query time, so, pick the option that best suits the context in which the query is run. When performance matters, I find it best to test out query & function performance using manually constructed sql & logic, and then work backwards and write the corresponding sqlalchemy expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct the same query that `lazy="dynamic"` does by using [`.with_parent`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_parent).

```
class Parent(Base):
    ...
    @property
    def children_dynamic(self):
        return object_session(self).query(Child).with_parent(self, Parent.children)
```

You can even add a function to reduce boilerplate if you have to write a lot of these:

```
def dynamicize(rel):
    @property
    def _getter(self):
        return object_session(self).query(rel.parent).with_parent(self, rel)
    return _getter

class Parent(Base):
    ...
    children = relationship("Child")
    children_dynamic = dynamicize(children)
```

Comment: According to [the document](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_parent.params.property), the `property` parameter can be omitted, so I think it can be shorten to `object_session(self).query(Child).with_parent(self)`

Comment: Also, I'm having some trouble understanding this: are `relationship("Child")` and `object_session(self).query(Child).with_parent(self, Parent.children).all()` and `object_session(self).query(Child).filter(parent=self).all()`(assuming we have `backref='parent'` in the relationship) equivalent?

Comment: @SunQingyao If you had a backref to `children` called `parent`, then `.filter(Child.parent == self)` would be functionally equivalent to `.with_parent(self, Parent.children)`, but I think there are minor differences in the way the SQL is rendered. The former is also less generic, because it assumes a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a function like that one, you don't even need to load all of the child objects in memory.
When you want to search for a child with a certain attribute, you can do:

```
# get a session object, usually with sessionmaker() configured to bind to your engine instance
c = session.query(Child).filter_by(some_attribute="some value here").all() # returns a list of all child objects that match the filter
# or: to get a child who belongs to a certain parrent with a certain attribute:
# get the parent object (p)
c = session.query(Child).filter_by(feed_type_id=p.id).filter_by(some_attr="some attribute that belongs to children of the p parrent object")
```

Comment: Both case you quering child table with 10000+ rows I want to filter from parent since just quering between 10 and 30 record

Answer (score 0):

No one strategy will give you everything.  However, you can  choose a default strategy and then override it.
My recommendation would be to:

- Add lazy = "joined" to your relationship so that by default, you will get all the parents.
- In cases where you want to query for a set of children dependent on properties of their parents but don't need the parent objects, use the join function on the query and filters referring both to the parent and child
- In cases where you need to  construct a query similar to what lazy = "dynamic" would do,  use the sqlalchemy.orm.defer operator to turn off your lazy = "joined" eager loading and the [loading interface](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.deferred)( to override eager loading and then use with_parent to construct  query. a query like you would have gotten with lazy = "dynamic"

Comment: What do you means by "dynamically filter children"?

Comment: @Overflow012 clarified what I meant in the answer; I meant like you get with lazy = "dynamic"